# Не компилируется код

Tags: массивы, c++builder, c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
int Kliuci,X,Y,a,b,interval=10;
float T,sum=0;
m3:
clrscr();
printf("\n\r  *****************\n\r");
printf("     1|FOR\n\r");
printf("     2|WHILE\n\r");
printf("     0|EXIT\n\r");
printf("       ****************\n\r");
printf("Vvedite Kliuci:");
scanf("%d",&Kliuci);
switch(Kliuci)
{case 1 :
{//for
printf("Vvedite znacenia:a,b\n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
printf("Vvedite interval min 10 X=n<Y+Y:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&X,&Y);
printf("\n\r   ********RESULT*******\r");
printf("\n\r    --Interval-----Rezulitat\n\r");
for(int k=X*X;k<Y+1;k++)
{
T=pow(b,2)+a/2+(pow(a,4)/4)-(pow(b,6)/6)+k;
printf("  |\t %d",k);
printf("-");
printf("\t  %f \n\r",T);
interval++;
sum+=T; }
printf("\n\r  *********************\n\r");
printf("Vesi interval:%d\n\r",interval);
printf("Vesi rezulitat: %f",sum);
getch();}
break;
case 2:
{//while
printf("Vvedite znacenia:a,b\n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
printf("Vvedite interval min 10 X=n<Y+Y:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&X,&Y);
printf("\n\r   ********RESULT********\r");
printf("\n\r    --Interval-----Rezulitat\n\r");
int k=X*X;
while(k<Y+1)
T=pow(b,2)+a/2+(pow(a,4)/4)-(pow(b,6)/6)+k;
k++;
printf("  |\t %d",k);
printf("-");
printf("\t  %f \n\r",T);
interval++;
sum+=T; }
printf("\n\r  **********************\n\r");
printf("Vesi interval:%d\n\r",interval);
printf("Vesi rezulitat: %f",sum);
getch();
break;
case 0:
exit(0); }
break;
}
goto m3;}
```

Comment: Найдите кнопочку 101010, и перешите заголовок. Уважайте людей-то, вот веселуха-то это месиво читать.

Comment: brain fuck ^^

Comment: GOTO!!! YEAH! 

*C++ что ли, я пас*

Comment: Какой компилятор, какая система, что именно не работает и что при этом пишет?

И вообще, форматируйте текст программы нормально, пишите с отступами, комментируйте. Уважайте других людей.

Comment: * [Хорошая книга для начала (MS Visual C++)][1]
 * [Обучение C++ с нуля][2]
 * [Хороший учебник по C++][3]
 * [С чего начать изучение языка программирования? Например C++.][4]
 * [Учебники для углубленного изучения C++][5]
 * [Какой самоучитель выбрать?][6]
 * [Левелап хеллоуворлдщика][7]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/29229
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/27099
  [3]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/35578
  [4]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/12767
  [5]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/38752
  [6]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/30531
  [7]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/25193

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку выдаёт - не указано в вопросе. На закрытие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что нашел - исправил. ТС - отступы!!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){
  int Kliuci,X,Y,a,b,interval=10;
  float T,sum=0;
  m3:
  clrscr();
  printf("\n\r  *****************\n\r");
  printf("     1|FOR\n\r");
  printf("     2|WHILE\n\r");
  printf("     0|EXIT\n\r");
  printf("       ****************\n\r");
  printf("Vvedite Kliuci:");
  scanf("%d",&Kliuci);

  switch(Kliuci){
    case 1 : {//for
      printf("Vvedite znacenia:a,b\n");
      scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
      printf("Vvedite interval min 10 X=n<Y+Y:\n");
      scanf("%d%d",&X,&Y);
      printf("\n\r   ********RESULT*******\r");
      printf("\n\r    --Interval-----Rezulitat\n\r");
      for(int k=X*X;k<Y+1;k++){
        T=pow(b,2)+a/2+(pow(a,4)/4)-(pow(b,6)/6)+k;
        printf("  |\t %d",k);
        printf("-");
        printf("\t  %f \n\r",T);
        interval++;
        sum+=T;
      }
      printf("\n\r  *********************\n\r");
      printf("Vesi interval:%d\n\r",interval);
      printf("Vesi rezulitat: %f",sum);
      getch();
    }
    break;
    case 2: {//while
      printf("Vvedite znacenia:a,b\n");
      scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
      printf("Vvedite interval min 10 X=n<Y+Y:\n");
      scanf("%d%d",&X,&Y);
      printf("\n\r   ********RESULT********\r");
      printf("\n\r    --Interval-----Rezulitat\n\r");
      int k=X*X;
      while(k<Y+1){
        T=pow(b,2)+a/2+(pow(a,4)/4)-(pow(b,6)/6)+k;
        k++;
        printf("  |\t %d",k);
        printf("-");
        printf("\t  %f \n\r",T);
        interval++;
        sum+=T;
      }
      printf("\n\r  **********************\n\r");
      printf("Vesi interval:%d\n\r",interval);
      printf("Vesi rezulitat: %f",sum);
      getch();
    }
    break;
    case 0:
      exit(0);
    break;
  }

  goto m3;
}
```

Comment: Проверил. Работает.

Answer (score 3):

Советую отказаться от `goto`.
Также если вы пишете на С++, то проявите уважение к `iostream`.

```
cout << T;  
cin >> T;
```

еще никто не отменял, выглядит проще и понятнее (`printf` немного путает, приходится думать)).

Comment: нормальный `printf`.